# Text is displayed distorted in the process of opening Sidebar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

We use chakra ui and react.
We created a sidebar that expands horizontally when a button is pressed.
However, the text is distorted when it expands horizontally.
I can not solve this problem.
The code is in codesanboxn.

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-leftpad-7ue9kr?file=/src/index.js)